# Why does Spark (on Google Dataproc) not use all vcores?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm running a spark job on a Google DataProc cluster. But looks like Spark is not using all the `vcores` available in the cluster as you can see below

[image: Cluster usage]

Based on some other questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368985/spark-on-yarn-too-less-vcores-used) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458063/why-does-vcore-always-equal-the-number-of-nodes-in-spark-on-yarn), i have setup the cluster to use `DominantResourceCalculator` to consider both vcpus and memory for resource allocation

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster_name --bucket="profiling-
job-default" \
--zone=europe-west1-c \
--master-boot-disk-size=500GB \
--worker-boot-disk-size=500GB \
--master-machine-type=n1-standard-16 \
--num-workers=10 \
--worker-machine-type=n1-standard-16 \
--initialization-actions gs://custom_init_gcp.sh \
--metadata MINICONDA_VARIANT=2 \
--properties=^--^yarn:yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
```

But when i submit my job with custom spark flags, looks like YARN doesn't respect these custom parameters and defaults to using memory as the yardstick for resource calculation

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster cluster_name \
--properties spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=900,spark.network.timeout=800\
,yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator\
,spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true\
,spark.executor.instances=10\
,spark.executor.cores=14\
,spark.executor.memory=15g\
,spark.driver.memory=50g \
src/my_python_file.py
```

Can help somebody figure out what's going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What I did wrong was to add the configuration `yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator` to `YARN` instead of the `capacity-scheduler.xml` (as it should be rightly) while cluster creation

Secondly, i changed `yarn:yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores` which was initially set to `1`.

I'm not sure if either one of these or both of these changes led to the solution (i will update soon). My new cluster  creation looks like below:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster_name --bucket="profiling-
job-default" \
--zone=europe-west1-c \
--master-boot-disk-size=500GB \
--worker-boot-disk-size=500GB \
--master-machine-type=n1-standard-16 \
--num-workers=10 \
--worker-machine-type=n1-standard-16 \
--initialization-actions gs://custom_init_gcp.sh \
--metadata MINICONDA_VARIANT=2 \
--properties=^--^yarn:yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores=4--capacity-scheduler:yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator
```

Comment: I tried it. You don't need yarn:yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores=4. It's the capacity-scheduler that does the trick!

Comment: Don't think this solution works. I am running spark 3.3 on yarn on dataproc and switching to dominant resource calculator doesn't change the cores per executor that yarn GUI reports

Answer (score 0):

First, as you have dynamic allocation enabled, you should set the properties `spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors` and `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation)

Second, make sure you have enough partitions in your spark job. As you are using dynamic allocation, yarn only allocates just enough executors to match the number of tasks (partitions). So check SparkUI whether your jobs (more specific : stages) have more than tasks than you have vCores available

Comment: Thank you for an answer. The link says that `spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors` is **relevant** however doesn't say they impact resource allocation. Can you comment more on this please? Secondly, my job had more than enough partitions (~3K) and increasing them only slowed things and decreasing led to memory issues. I posted an answer which worked for me.