# AWS EMR Containers not using all available cores

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have an EMR Cluster that has correctly spawned 6 executors, 4 cores each.
When the spark job is run on the cluster, it creates 6 Containers, which are each only assigned 1 core, How do i specify the number of cores each Container is allocated?

Relevant config:

```
spark.executor.instances: 5
spark.executor.cores: 4
yarn.scheduler.minimum.allocation.vcores: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be simply a reporting error with the Yarn UI as discussed here
[Dataproc set number of vcores per executor container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450536/dataproc-set-number-of-vcores-per-executor-container?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Spark UI shows the correct number of cores in the executors, and the log files from the application state that it has been assigned the correct number of cores.