# DataProc YARN UI - wrong number of Vcores

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc

im running a spark application on dataproc cluster (n1-standard-16) 4 machines (3 primary and 1 secondary)

in idle scenario i can see 16 vcores available which is expected.
[image]

but when my spark application is running it is going above 16 i.e 32.. like below, any idea why this is happening? is it because of threading concept?
[image]

if it is because of threading how to control it? and how i can make the maximum use out of it?

note: i have corrected the yarn ui scheduler type to fair scheduler already.

my spark request:
--properties=spark.submit.deployMode=cluster,spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true,spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreOrc=true,spark.hadoop.hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict,spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true,spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true,spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=30,spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=180,spark.dynamicAllocation.executorIdleTimeout=60s,spark.executor.instances=70,spark.executor.cores=3,spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer,spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=220,spark.executor.memory=3g,spark.driver.memory=2g,spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1g,

thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52450536/dataproc-set-number-of-vcores-per-executor-container

Comment: @Aravind Did you find the above comment helpful ?